# Aggregate by a dynamic field in Solr

Tags: solr, solrj, sunspot, solrnet

I have the following data in 2 indexes in Solr (indexing from app code)

1. Student
2. Class

All the raw data I have is at a student level. A student can be part of multiple classes. The problem is that a student can move in/out of classes and the class_id is not part of the student data that was sent.

I currently query aggregates faceted by 'student'. How do I query the same facets Class ID?

If I query for all the students in the class, I will get my result, but I need to loop through. Another solution is to use the student_ids and re-aggregate at a class level in the code. I want to check if there is any other solution which I can use in Solr.

(join in Solr are INNER JOINs and wont help much).

Is it possible to achieve this with the help of a plugin?

Say the data I have is the following.

```
student_id, points, activity_date
1, 10, 2017-01-01
1, 10, 2017-01-02
1, 10, 2017-01-03
2, 10, 2017-01-01
2, 10, 2017-01-03
3, 10, 2017-01-02
3, 10, 2017-01-03
3, 20, 2017-01-04

class_id, student_id
11,1
11,2
12,1
12,3
13,2
13,3
```

When I query by the students from 1st Jan to 4th Jan. I get 
    student_id, points
    1, 30
    2, 20
    3, 40

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/development/select?q=*%3A*&fq=type%3AStudent&wt=json&indent=true&stats=true&stats.field=points_i&f.points_i.stats.facet=id_i
```

This is what I need, outer join of students with class.
Example what I want when I query by all classes from 1st Jan to 4th Jan.

```
class_id, points
11, 50
12, 60
13, 70
```

How do I get this by class_id

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing your requirement - could you add a few examples of how the data would be structured and what you're trying to get out of Solr?

Comment: sure. will do that. essentially a left outer join of two tables.

Comment: If you're on a new enough version of Solr, [Streaming Expressions might be a solution](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/streaming-expressions.html).

Comment: Solr is a search engine, not a database. Try denormalizing data into 1 schema that has a multivalued class field